# Evaluate $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{k a_k }$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Let $ a_k $ a real sequence so that $ \lim_{k \to \infty} a_k = 0$. I am trying to prove or disprove that

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{k a_k } =0.$$

I only managed to prove it under stronger assumptions, for example $ a_k \in \mathcal{O}(\frac{1}{k^p}),~ p>0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Let $\varepsilon>0$ and let $N$ s.t. $$|a_k|<\varepsilon,$$
whenever $n\geq N$.

Then $$\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=N}^{n}k|a_k|\leq \frac{k(n-N+1)}{n^2}\varepsilon<\varepsilon.$$

I let you conclude.

Comment: Why the downvote ?

Comment: Not the downvoter, but the inequality should read $\leq \frac{n(n-N+1)}{n^2}\varepsilon$

Answer (score 1):

If $\lim_{k \rightarrow +\infty} a_k = 0$ then if you fix $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a $K \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|a_k| < \varepsilon$ when $k > K$. So, when for $n$ large enough ($n -1> K$)
$$0 \leq \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}ka_k < \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^K ka_k + \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=K+1}^{n-1}ka_k < \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^K ka_k+\frac{\varepsilon}{n^2}\Big((n-1-K)K+\frac{(n-K)(n-1-K)}{2}\Big)$$
hence when you take the limit for $n \rightarrow +\infty$ you get 
$$0 \leq \lim_n \frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}ka_k < \lim_n \Big(\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^K ka_k+\frac{\varepsilon}{n^2}\Big((n-1-K)K+\frac{(n-K)(n-1-K)}{2}\Big)\Big).$$
At the right hand side, the first sum is finite, so $\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=1}^{K}ka_k$ goes to $0$, whereas the second term goes to $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. So 
$$0 \leq \lim_n \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} ka_k < \varepsilon$$
and $\varepsilon$ is an arbitrary positive number. If the limit in the middle was positive you could always find $\varepsilon > 0$ small enough giving a contradiction. So $\lim_n \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}ka_k = 0$.